# Targeting SCSS variables in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, sass, gradient

I'd like the gradient I've put over a background image (both are background properties) to change when triggered by a scroll event (for starters... eventually I'd like to tie it to the scroll).

I've created a SCSS variable for the percentage of the gradient that I want to be each color.  I can't seem to target the correct property with my javascript.  What am I doing wrong?

I've made the change manually in my SCSS file and confirmed that the variable and the 95% property both work properly.

Thank you in advance!

SCSS:

```
body { 
    $percent-bg: 15%;
  background:  
    linear-gradient(
        to right,
        rgba(242, 63, 117, 0.45), 
        rgba(63, 242, 188, 0.45) $percent-bg
      ),
    url(http://media.giphy.com/media/5a6IkssTZRI08/giphy.gif) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
var scroll_pos = 0;
        $(document).scroll(function() { 
            scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
            if(scroll_pos > 10) {
                $(body).css('$percent-bg', '95%');
            } else {
                $(body).css('$percent-bg', '15%');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just use another class?

Comment: What makes you think you can manipulate Sass variables after it has been converted to CSS where there *are no Sass variables*?

Comment: @isherwood The next step is to tie this transition to the scroll, for which I'd need access to the percentage, because I can't gradually addClass.

Comment: Eau contraire. You can `toggleClass` with a switch and easing (though I admit I haven't tried it for this use case). http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleclass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't talk to Sass with JavaScript (Unless you have a *very* unique set-up going on. If so, tell us what it is.) because JavaScript occurs in the user agent (browser) while Sass is compiled in the back end into CSS, and it's the CSS that is delivered to the browser.

This is probably the best way do it. First, create a new class in the Sass that contains the styling you want. Ex:

```
body.scrooll { 
  $percent-bg: 95%;
  background:  
    linear-gradient(
        to right,
        rgba(242, 63, 117, 0.45), 
        rgba(63, 242, 188, 0.45) $percent-bg
      ),
    url(http://media.giphy.com/media/5a6IkssTZRI08/giphy.gif) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
```

Then use JavaScript apply and remove that class on scroll.

Comment: Thank you Katie!  The reason I chose not to use addClass initially is because my next step was tying it to the scroll, not just triggering it at 10px.  Do you know of another work around that may be helpful?  Either way thank you for explaining this SCSS/JS relationship.

Comment: You're welcome. Another workaround would be to have JavaScript fire some kind of call to the server, the server to re-process the Sass, and then have the browser-reload the page. But for your described needs, that would be a pretty hairy workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Used KatieK's approach and made a few other changes to get it working properly, here's the final code:

SCSS: (can also be CSS only... see notes)

```
body { 
    $percent-bg: 15%;
  background:  
    linear-gradient(
        to right,
        rgba(242, 63, 117, 0.45), 
        rgba(63, 242, 188, 0.45) $percent-bg
      ),
    url(http://media.giphy.com/media/5a6IkssTZRI08/giphy.gif) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

.scrooll {
    $percent-bg: 95%;
  background:  
    linear-gradient(
        to right,
        rgba(242, 63, 117, 0.45), 
        rgba(63, 242, 188, 0.45) $percent-bg
      ),
    url(http://media.giphy.com/media/5a6IkssTZRI08/giphy.gif) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    var scroll_pos = 0;
        $(document).scroll(function() { 
            scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
            if(scroll_pos > 10) {
                $("body").addClass("scrooll");
            } else {
                $("body").removeClass("scrooll");
            }
        });
});
```

Notes: $(body) in my js needed to be $("body").  Also, now that we're using two classes, $percent-bg is no longer needed.  Regular CSS can be used with the percentage replacing $percent-bg after the second rgba.